# memcached - using with a C# asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, caching, memcached

I'm considering using memcached (at some point) in my application i'm currently developing.

Eventually, i'm planning on hosting this on Amazon EC2 - 
i was just wondering, would it be possible to have a linux server (aws instance) running memcached, and use the windows server (aws instance) for the app, but set it to use the linux server for the cache??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible. I suggest using the [enyim.com client](http://memcached.enyim.com/) instead of the "official one" as it a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the MemCached service if you use NHibernate NHContrib extension for memcache at http://nhcontrib.wiki.sourceforge.net/