# Running Memcached for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, memcached

I want to start using memcached in my ASP.NET application.

I think I need to set up a memcached server and then access it using a .NET specific client.

However I'm struggling to see how to set it up, where to find the exact downloads for .NET and so on

---

**Found the answer I was looking for in these questions**

- [Is there a port of memcache to .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276924/is-there-a-port-of-memcache-to-net)
- [memcached - using with a C# asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124776/memcached-using-with-a-c-asp-net-application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a port of memcache to .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276924/is-there-a-port-of-memcache-to-net)